# How to update Activity UI from broadcast receiver without creating sub class of receiver inside the activity in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I am receiving broadcast from another app in frequent interval. When I first receive the broadcast it shows the message data received from the broadcast by opening the activity. But after the activity is opened and I receive another broadcast, it is not updating that value in the Activity.
I don't want to create the subclass of receiver in my activity class because I want to register the receiver on manifest file.

This is my receiver code.

```
         val activity = Intent(context, DisplayUpdate::class.java)
         activity.putExtra("Key", intent.extras!!.getString("Key"))
         activity.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
         context.startActivity(activity)
```

This is my isplayUpdate Activity code.

```
    val bundle = intent.extras!!.getString("Key")


    binding.textview.text = bundle
    when (bundle!!.toInt()) {
        200 -> {
            Log.d("notiapp", "onCreate: when 200")
            binding.textview.text = "Downloading"
        }
        300 -> {
            Log.d("notiapp", "onCreate: when 300")
            binding.textview.text = "Verifying"
        }
        400 -> {
            Log.d("notiapp", "onCreate: when 400")
            binding.textview.text = "Installing"
        }
        else ->
            binding.textview.text = "No Updates"
    }
```

Another way in which I am doing this is to show the notification when I receive the broadcast. When I click on notification it opens the activity with the message received from the broadcast. But here also I am getting the same issue which is when I click on first notification it opens the activity but after clicking on second or third notification it doesn't reopen the activity or change the value of the message in the activity.

This implementation in below.

```
 val intent1 = Intent(context, DisplayUpdate::class.java)
    intent1.putExtra("Key", intent?.extras!!.getString("Key").toString())
    intent1.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

    if (intent?.extras!!.getString("Key").toString() == "200") {

        // Prepare a notification with vibration, sound and lights
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle("Downloading")
            .setContentText("notificationText")
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 400, 250, 400))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent1,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            )

        // Automatically configure a Notification Channel for devices running Android O+
        Pushy.setNotificationChannel(builder, context)

        // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        // Build the notification and display it
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
    } else if (intent?.extras!!.getString("Key").toString() == "300") {
        // Prepare a notification with vibration, sound and lights
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle("Downloaded")
            .setContentText("notificationText")
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 400, 250, 400))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent1,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            )

        // Automatically configure a Notification Channel for devices running Android O+
        Pushy.setNotificationChannel(builder, context)

        // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        // Build the notification and display it
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
    } else if (intent?.extras!!.getString("Key").toString() == "400") {
        // Prepare a notification with vibration, sound and lights
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle("Verifying")
            .setContentText("notificationText")
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 400, 250, 400))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent1,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            )

        // Automatically configure a Notification Channel for devices running Android O+
        Pushy.setNotificationChannel(builder, context)

        // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        // Build the notification and display it
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
    }
```

Do I need to provide any more details ?

Thanks.

Comment: "This is my receiver code" -- that makes little sense. If you are receiving broadcasts "in frequent interval", you should not be starting activities that frequently. And, if "[you] want to register the receiver on manifest file", you cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android (plus, users of older devices will be *very* irritated when you basically spam their screens with your activity). Have your `BroadcastReceiver` update some singleton, which then updates the rest of your app via a reactive API (`LiveData`, `StateFlow`, RxJava, etc.).

Comment: So the idea over here is that I have created a service app which checks for firmware update from server using JNI. Based on the response from the server it prompts the user to update the firmware. This response is sent to another app (which I mentioned in the question) using broadcast. There are 4 responses (Downloading, Downloaded, Verifying, Installling). For now I was sending this 4 response in 10 sec interval. I want this response to be updated in my activity's UI. If possible without starting the activity. This is my first question so if I don't make any sense then let me know.

Comment: Have your `BroadcastReceiver` update some singleton, which then updates the rest of your app via a reactive API (`LiveData`, `StateFlow`, RxJava, etc.).